# Cast a struct member in GDB Pretty Print?

Tags: c, gdb, pretty-print, gdb-python

I want to pretty print this struct `struct MyStruct { char buffer[16]; }`. Depending on buffer[15] I want to print buffer as a 10 byte string or treat it as a pointer. The 10 byte case is simple and works `return self.val['buffer'].string(length = 10)`

The second case I can't figure out. I want to do something like `(*(char**)buffer[0])`. I'm not sure how to do that. I was thinking parse_and_eval could be easy even if its not optimal but I couldn't figure out how to access buffer. I also need to cast the buffer to a 32bit int (`len = *(int*)(bufer+4);`) I couldn't figure that out either.

Comment: You wrote as example `(*(char**)buffer[0])`, but here you cast only the first byte to a pointer, that can't be right. Did you mean `(*(char**)&buffer[0])`?

Comment: @ssbssa my mistake. I forgot the & or I should have not written `[0]`. The second case I don't know how to do is casting so I can access the struct like this `AltStruct{char*p; int size, flag;};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret your description correctly, I think your data is actually layed out like this:

```c
struct MyStruct {
    union {
        char string[10];
        struct {
            char *p;
            int size;
        } ptr;
    }
    int flag;
}
```

So I think casting the buffer to a pointer of that type, and then choosing the format based on `mystruct->flag` would make life easier for you.

Even if my interpretation is not correct, try to find the correct version of that `struct` that captures the duality of the data.

Comment: I'll accept this because it's what ended up doing. I thought I could cast in the python code but gave up and changed the type in my actual code